# enable/disable an optionmenu item from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-optionsmenu

Guys can I possibly disable/enable an optionmenu item from a button inside fragments? On my project I wanna disable a specific menu item once I successfully log-in from fragment. Example I have this Enter(button) inside fragment layout, once the username and password is correct what I want is to disable the log-in optionmenu item. Guys can u give me some example on how to code it? Thank you so much in advance guys!!! :')

Answer (score 0):

Call `InvalidateOptionsMenu` or `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu` when you want to change the menu.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()

this will cause `OnPrepareOptionsMenu` to be called where you can make whatever changes you like to your menu. For example, disable or hide a "Log In" option if you are already logged in.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can enable/disable `optionmenu` item from fragment. Override these methods in fragment.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menuItem1).setEnabled(false/true);
}
```